# MOXy - Serializing and Deserializing of Enums using Jackson2 Annotations (Weblogic 12.2.1.3)

Tags: json, enums, weblogic

Suppose, we have 2 RESTful webservices (JAX-RS). The first service acts as a consumer and calls the API of the second service. The second service (provider) is generated using the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` with jaxrs-spec option and an underlying .yml-file describing the API. Both the provider- and the consumer webservices are deployed successfully on the Weblogic application server and serve requests as expected...

... with one little exception. The serialization / deserialization of Enums is not working as expected. Eums are generated with the corresponding Jackson2 Annotations `@JsonValue` and `@Jsoncreator`:

```
public enum MyEnum {
   FIRST_VALUE("first_value"),
   SECOND_VALUE("second_value");

   private static Map<String, MyEnum> ENUM_MAP = Stream
        .of(MyEnum.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.formatted, Function.identity()));

   private final String value;

   private MyEnum(String value) { this.value = value; }

   @JsonValue 
   public String value() { return value; }

   @JsonCreator
   public static MyEnum fromString(String string) {
        return Optional
            .ofNullable(ENUM_MAP.get(string))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(string));
    }

}
```

The expectation would be (assuming the Jackson annotations would not be ignored by the ObjectMapper) that a Java object `MyEnum.FIRST_VALUE` gets serialized as `{"first_value"}`. However, the result (what the provider webservice receives and the consumer webservice sends) is `{"FIRST_VALUE"}`. How come? Weblogic uses MOXy as default JSON provider. And MOXy ignores the above mentioned Jackson2 Annotations.

The question, therefore is: How can I make the webservice receive `{"first_value"}` instead of `{"FIRST_VALUE"}` **and** how am I supposed to adjust my JAX-RS Jersey Client (in the first webservice) in order to pass the value `{"first_value"}` to my second webservice when called using

```
Client client = ClientBuilder().newClient();
client.target(MY_URI)
      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .post(Entity.entity(MyEnum.FIRST_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

I tried the following:

1. Finding out that serialization / deserialization works correctly in a Java SE environment when we use Jackson as JSON provider (after adding the corresponding maven coordinates). Please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689107/deserializing-an-enum-with-jackson), my example Enum looks the same (plus `@JsonValue` Annotation, minus `@JsonProperty`). However, serialization works as expected in a Java SE Unit-Test
2. Finding out that MOXy needs JAXB-Annotations, so we could use the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate JAXB-Annotations. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153862/swagger-codegen-missing-jaxb-annotations-with-jaxrs-spec). Seems a little too complicated to achieve the goal.
3. Writing a custom XmlAdapter, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702924/how-to-write-a-jsonstructure-jsr-353-xmladaptor-for-jaxb-moxy). Why would we do that, when Jackson does the marshalling out of the box?
4. Disable MOXy as default JSON provider, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813309/weblogic-12-2-1-3-from-moxy-to-jackson). Actually, **this solves the problem on the producer side**, but what about the consumer? The client still sends the "wrong" JSON, so that the service throws an Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem. Hopefully this will be helpful to some poor soul struggling with the same problem. As I have already pointed out in my original question, the solution is to disable MOXy:

**Provider:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties()
    {
        Map<String, Object> proprties = new HashMap<>();
        proprties.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);

        return proprties;
    }
}
```

See also [Weblogic 12.2.1.3 from Moxy to Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813309/weblogic-12-2-1-3-from-moxy-to-jackson)

**Consumer:**

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient().register(Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature"));
```

This will do the trick on the client side.

See also [Weblogic 12.2.1.2 - How to tune the object Serializer to use Jackson 2 and strange phenomena on jaxrs enablement for application/json endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652675/weblogic-12-2-1-2-how-to-tune-the-object-serializer-to-use-jackson-2-and-stran)

Kudos to 99Sono. Thank you so much for ending this odyssey!